# T student distribution

Tags: statistics

I have a population with 10000 individual, i took 10 to my samples.
The values that i have inside $\bar{X}$
70,22502193
70,26042017
70,28977621
70,2905717
70,30113496
70,32304453
70,32489699
70,3434273
70,41455295
70,46876484

$\mu$ = 50.03385
$\bar{X}$ = 70.32416
$S$ = 0.071637
N = 10.

I need to find $P(|\bar{X}-\mu| < t * S * \sqrt{10}$
i used the t formula = $T=\frac{70.32416-50.03385}{\frac{0.071637}{\sqrt{10}}}$ the result was 895.677, is this correct?

in the another question, i cant figure out how to do it.
$\bar{X} $ and $ S^{2} = 120 $ whats the probability to find t lower than produced by $\bar{X}$

And, $S^{2} = 120, P(|\bar{X} - \mu| < 0.3)$ i find the Pr using the $P(|\bar{X}-\mu| < t * S * \sqrt{10})$ formula?